# Keep products in shopping cart after customer logs out

Tags: magento-enterprise, quote, customer-account, customer-session, quoteitem

I am trying to find a way to keep a customer shopping cart items in the shopping cart after they have logged out.

I have enabled persistence already which is fine as long as the customer logs back in their shopping cart items are visible.

What I would like to do is keep them visible when they log out until they click empty cart.

So far I have added an Observer to hook into `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_logoutSuccess`
Then in my Observer I have

```
    public function preserveQuote(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($observer->getCustomer());
        $currentQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $currentQuote->merge($customerQuote);
    }
```

This logic doesn't work as I think the session has already been cleared by the time the Observer does it's thing.

Has anyone come across a better way to do it?

Please let me know as always very appreciative...

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code:

```
public function preserveQuote(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($observer->getCustomer());
    $currentQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $currentQuote->merge($customerQuote);
}
```

And it works but I used this observer:

```
    <events>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers>
                <pengo_customer_logout_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Pengo_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>preserveQuote</method>
                </pengo_customer_logout_observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_logout>
    </events>
```

Now Cart items persist when i logout.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and confirmation, for me I still see an empty shopping cart when I've logged out. However, logging back in I can see the items but for some reason the code isn't working for me...

Comment: You must Disable `Persistent Shopping Cart` after that you'll able to see your cart when you logout

Comment: Still not working, I'm going to try on a default install and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Observer wasn't neccessary and instead enabled persistence in admin then included                     `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>` inside `persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

The cart is now persistent when logged out!!